# Problema con la librería multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x

He estado tratando de entender la librería multiprocessing.
Uno de los ejercicios que estaba tratando de hacer era este, pero aun con cadenas simples como `aaaaaaaac` el programa no es capaz de encontrar la cadena y no tengo idea de por qué.

Si alguien puede ayudarme, adjunto el código que uso:

```py
import itertools
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f_mayusculas_minusculas(c, queue):
    for i in range(8, 129):
        for combination in itertools.product(*(['abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ']*i)):
            s = ''.join(combination)
            if s == c:
                queue.put(s)

def f_mayusculas(c, queue):
    for i in range(8, 129):
        for combination in itertools.product(*(['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ']*i)):
            s = ''.join(combination)
            if s == c:
                queue.put(s)

def f_numeros(c, queue):
    for i in range(8, 129):
        for combination in itertools.product(*(['0123456789']*i)):
            s = ''.join(combination)
            if s == c:
                queue.put(s)

def f_num_let(c, queue):
    for i in range(8, 129):
        for combination in itertools.product(*(['abcdefghijklmñnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789']*i)):
            s = ''.join(combination)
            if s == c:
                queue.put(s)

def f_es(c, queue):
    for i in range(8, 129):
        for combination in itertools.product(*(['¿?¡!#$%&/()=''"*\\<>°.,:;@+-_   ']*i)):
            s = ''.join(combination)
            if s == c:
                queue.put(s)

def f_may_num(c, queue):
    for i in range(8, 129):
        for combination in itertools.product(*(['ABCDEFGHIJKLMÑNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789']*i)):
            s = ''.join(combination)
            if s == c:
                queue.put(s)

def f_l_es(c, queue):
    for i in range(8, 129):
        for combination in itertools.product(*(['abcdefghijklmñnopqrstuvwxyz¿?¡!#$%&/()=''"*\\<>°.,:;@+-_   ']*i)):
            s = ''.join(combination)
            if s == c:
                queue.put(s)

def f_lm_es(c, queue):
    for i in range(8, 129):
        for combination in itertools.product(*(['ABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ¿?¡!#$%&/()=''"*\\<>°.,:;@+-_   ']*i)):
            s = ''.join(combination)
            if s == c:
                queue.put(s)

def f_todo(c, queue):
    for i in range(8, 129):
        for combination in itertools.product(*(['abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNÑOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789¿?¡!#$%&/()=''"*\\<>°.,:;@+-_   ']*i)):
            s = ''.join(combination)
            if s == c:
                queue.put(s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = input("Ingrese el valor objetivo: ")
    queue = Queue()
    processes = [
        Process(target=f_es, args=(c, queue)),
        Process(target=f_numeros, args=(c, queue)),
        Process(target=f_may_num, args=(c, queue)),
        Process(target=f_todo, args=(c, queue)),
        Process(target=f_num_let, args=(c, queue))
    ]
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    found = False
    while not queue.empty():
        result = queue.get()
        found = True
        print(f"Felicidades, c es {result}")
    if not found:
        print(f"No se encontró la cadena objetivo {c}")
    for process in processes:
        process.terminate()
```

En teoría, este código realiza un proceso de fuerza bruta para sacar el valor de `c` pero el código es incapaz de hacerlo sin importar cuán fácil sea `c`.

Comment: No está relacionado con tu pregunta, pero te recomiendo usar el argumento `repeat` al llamar a [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu cadena `c = "aaaaaaaac"` tiene 9 caracteres.
Todas tus funciones empiezan generando cadenas de 8 caracteres.
La función que primero generará `c` es `f_num_let`.
Pero antes de generar `c` tendrá que generar todas las combinaciones posibles de longitud 8.
Eso son 37^8, lo cual es del orden de 10^12.
En mi máquina tarda 9,91 segundos en comprobar las 50 millones primeras cadenas.
Haciendo una regla de tres, tardará más de 8 días en llegar a generar `c`.

En tu caso inicias todos los procesos e inmediatamente después preguntas si alguno de ellos ha encontrado `c`.
Desde que inicias los procesos hasta que compruebas `queue.empty()` no han pasado 8 días.
Por lo tanto es imposible que ningún proceso haya añadido ningún elemento a `queue`.
La condición del bucle `while` es falsa y continúa la ejecución del código.
Por consiguiente imprime por consola que no se ha encontrado la cadena objetivo.

Si quisieras poner tu programa a esperar 8 días, tendrías que escribir un [`get`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.get):

```py
while result := queue.get():
    found = True
    print(f"Felicidades, c es {result}")
```

El problema de este bucle es que cuando acaben todos los procesos de `processes`, el `get` seguirá esperando.
Para indicar que todos los procesos han terminado es habitual usar un [Sentinel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value).
Según el [PEP 661](https://peps.python.org/pep-0661/) una manera habitual de definirlo es esta: `_sentinel = object()`, pero a nosotros [no nos sirve](https://peps.python.org/pep-0661/#use-notgiven-object) porque lo vamos a meter en una `Queue` y el objeto introducido tendría una dirección de memoria distinta.
Usaremos `None` como sentinel.
Nosotros añadiremos nuestro sentinel cuando todos los procesos se hayan completado.

```py
AllThreadsAreDone = None

def notify_when_done(processes: list[Process], queue: Queue):
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    queue.put(AllThreadsAreDone)
```

El resto del código quedaría:

```py
processes = ...
Thread(target=notify_when_done, args=(processes, queue)).start()
found = False
while (result := queue.get()) is not AllThreadsAreDone:
    found = True
    print(f"Felicidades, c es {result}")
```

Es importante que la función `notify_when_done` no sea llamada en un proceso nuevo.
En su lugar usamos un [`threading.Thread`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread).
Hay dos motivos:

- No se puede llamar `start` a un proceso desde un proceso distinto a aquel que lo creó (como se indica al final de la documentación de [`multiprocessing.Process`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.close)).
  De lo contrario, saltará un [`AssertionError`:
  *can only start a process object created by current process*](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2ca008e2b738b8c08b4bf46b2b23f315d6510d92/Lib/multiprocessing/process.py#L116).
  Como los procesos en `processes` los hemos creado en el proceso principal, tenemos que llamar a sus `start` sin crear un proceso nuevo.
- Al crear un nuevo proceso no podemos usar como `args` procesos ya iniciados.
  Eso se debe a que [todos los elementos de `args` deben ser serializables](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods) y [los procesos no son serializables](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/91090) tras llamar su método `start` (hay líneas de trabajo abiertas para corregir esto: [gh-91090](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/31701)).
  De lo contrario obtendremos una excepción `TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref.ReferenceType' object`.